# How to sort and search json array using java

Tags: java, json

My Json file is like this

```
{
"Hello" : [{
      "CommentId":28227,
      "Comments":"User Philip John has added a new file",
      "DisplayComments":"User <a id='getUser' data='205' >Philip John</a> has added a new file.",
      "Users":[
         { "UserId":"1", "UserName":"User one" },
         { "UserId":"2", "UserName":"User two" }
      ]
},{
      "CommentId":28226,
      "Comments":"docs",
      "DisplayComments":"docs",
      "RefCommentId":28226,
      "IsSystemGenerated":0,
      "CommentDate":"2014-09-17T06:51:47.317",
      "Users": [
         {"UserId":"1","UserName":"User one"},
         {"UserId":"3","UserName":"User Three"}
         ]
},{
      "CommentId":28225,
      "Comments":"New Group aa has been created.",
      "DisplayComments":"New Group <a id='getGroup' data='88' >aa</a> has been created.",
      "RefCommentId":28225,
      "IsSystemGenerated":1,
      "CommentDate":"2014-09-16T07:21:38.493",
      "Users":[
         {"UserId":"3","UserName":"User three"},
         {"UserId":"4","UserName":"User four" }
      ]
},{
      "CommentId":28224,
      "Comments":"New Group Philip has been created.",
      "DisplayComments":"New Group <a id='getGroup' data='87' >ss</a> has been created.",
      "RefCommentId":28224,
      "IsSystemGenerated":1,
      "CommentDate":"2014-09-16T06:00:58.897",
      "Users":null
}]}
```

Comment: Using Boon how i sort JsonArray or is there any other process to sort and search Json data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all probably good idea is to define model classes which will contain your json data. You will be able then easy to operate with that data later and also your code will be more "clean" in general.

```
public class Hello{
    private String commentId;
    private String comments;
    private Date commentDate;

    // ... other fields
    // getters and setters...
}
```

In your own answer you posted example with JSONParser&JSONObject classes. You can use those classes then to fill data into you model classes.

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);
JSONArray lang= (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Hello");

List<Hello> objs = new ArrayList<Hello>();

for (int i = 0; i < lang.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject rec = lang.getJSONObject(i);
    String commentId = rec.getInt("CommentId");
    String comments = rec.getString("Comments");
    // ...

    Hello h = new Hello();
    h.setCommentId(commentId);
    h.setComments(comments);
    // ...

    // store you objects into list
    objs.add(h);
}
```

Then you can use Collections class to sort data in list by date for e.g. like:

```
Collections.sort(objs, new Comparator<Hello>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Hello o1, Hello o2) {
        return o1.getCommentDate().compareTo(o2.getCommentDate());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I Tried like this but i am unable search and sort the element.
private static final String filePath = "E:\List.json";

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);


        JSONArray lang= (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Hello");

        Map<JSONObject, String> jsonValues = new TreeMap<JSONObject, String>();

        for(int i=0; i<lang.size(); i++){
            jsonValues.putAll((JSONObject) lang.get(i));
            System.out.println(jsonValues.toString());

        }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```